# Why does Windows 8 take so long to discover it's connected to Wifi?

Tags: networking, windows-8

Whenever I restart Windows (from scratch or hibernate), Windows 8 takes forever to discover it's connected to the wifi. I say "discover" because the tray icon shows it's connected and pings to my router work fine right way, but my browser (IE or Chrome) or Windows 8 apps all believe there is no connection.

What am I missing?

Dell Latitude E6500
Dell Wireless 1500 Wireless WLAN card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple months of living with this, the problem got so bad the computer wouldn't connect at all.  in desperation, I ran the network troubleshooter and it did a repair on the connection. Since then network connections are almost immediate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Windows bug. I have seen this issue with all the computers in our house; HP with Qualcomm and Gateway with Broadcom. I have done some research on this myself and that's what turned up. The hardware is fine.

The most common issue is the Windows 8 Metro apps. For some odd reason they take the longest time to realise there is an active connection. The App Store from time to time thinks I have disconnected the internet.